# Reading htmls encoded in windows-1251 (rus)

Tags: xml, r, encoding

I have some problems parsing html file encoded in windows-1251 or CP1251 (russian).
Given the html file, as an example:

```
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" width="100%">
                          <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <td class="xl27" align="center">Место</td>
                            <td class="xl27" align="center">ПИФ</td>
                            <td class="xl27" align="center">УК</td>
                            <td class="xl27" align="center">Тип фонда</td>
                            <td class="xl27" align="center">Категория фонда</td>
                            <td class="xl27" align="center">Специализация</td>
                            <td class="xl27" align="center">Доходность</td>
                           </tr></table>
```

I run the following script:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Russian_Russia.1251")
require(XML)
htmlfile<-paste('C:\\YourWD\\data.html')
htable<-readHTMLTable(htmlfile)[[1]]
```

And the output for htable[1,1] is something like "РњРµСЃС‚Рѕ"
Encoding of which is determined as "unknown" by

```
unique(sapply(tab,function(x)Encoding(as.character(x))))
```

Thanks in advance!